# How to call cellForItemAtIndexPath on a cell without lose its selected state?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a collectionView whose cell need to change its image and change border color when clicked.

I have overridden `setSelected:` in the subclass of UICollectionViewCell to change border color, and changed image in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`. But I don't know how to make them both work after I have selected a cell, `cellForItemAtIndexPath` is not called in this situation. If I explicitly call `reloadData` or `reloadCellAtIndexPath` and I don't know whether cell is selected in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`.

I don't want to move the specific code in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` , because it is obviously that I need to copy the code in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` to `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`, and I don't want to repeat myself.

I don't want to add a property to save the index of the clicked cell, because there's no need to add such parameter which can be easily found by `[collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems]`.

Also I don't want to add a property to reference to my data model(which contains the images), because it's weird.

So, should I write all of those in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`? Or is there any method to call `cellForItemAtIndexPath` directly without clear the selected state?

Comment: it is simple, you just need to store the selected-state in your _model_, and when you'll need to recreate a cell for an index-path you can restore such information from there as well, next to all other custom info which you'd need to populate your cell.

Answer (score 0):

When creating the cell, can't you just pass both the selected and the unselected image to it and let the cell decide which one to show? You then don't have to have a reference to your model in the cell itself, and you can still use the override on setSelected to change the visuals of the cell.

Another way would be to give the cell a delegate property and let it ask for a new image when it needs to have one.